# Best way to total distinct values of a Bean inside of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections

I have an ArrayList of a Bean.  Inside the bean are two properties "String monthYear" and "double bill" I need to add and get the total bill based on the monthYear.

For Example based from the code below I need to get the output of

```
 JAN-2013 = 210
 FEB-2013 = 20 
 NOV-2012 = 130 
 DEC-2012 = 40

public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BillsBean> billList = new ArrayList<BillsBean>();

        BillsBean bills1 = new BillsBean();
        bills1.setMonthYear("JAN-2013");
        bills1.setBill(10);
        billList.add(bills1);

        BillsBean bills2 = new BillsBean();     
        bills2.setMonthYear("FEB-2013");
        bills2.setBill(20);
        billList.add(bills2);

        BillsBean bills3 = new BillsBean();
        bills3.setMonthYear("NOV-2012");
        bills3.setBill(30);
        billList.add(bills3);

        BillsBean bills4 = new BillsBean();
        bills4.setMonthYear("DEC-2012");
        bills4.setBill(40);
        billList.add(bills4);

        BillsBean bills5 = new BillsBean();
        bills5.setMonthYear("NOV-2012");
        bills5.setBill(100);
        billList.add(bills5);

        BillsBean bills6 = new BillsBean();
        bills6.setMonthYear("JAN-2013");
        bills6.setBill(200);
        billList.add(bills6);
}
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-loop-arraylist-in-java/ and alternatively you can use something called "Iterator"

Comment: *I need to get the output of* -- of what ?

Comment: @luiggiMendoza I am well aware of the enhanced for loop and the Iterator I could group them as I iterate and add them and come up with the output. As you said more than 600 rep so you could have atleast assumed that I was looking for the best way to do it as sir vels4j professionally did.

Comment: @royjavelosa your question content doesn't reflect what you posted in your last comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza and my question also did not ask on how to iterate through an ArrayList which you immediately assumed.  Others understood it and posted their answers.  Still Id apologize if it was not that clear to you.  But I'd gladly appreciate if you could post your own solution like others did.

Comment: @NoobUnChained JAN-2013 = 210
 FEB-2013 = 20 
 NOV-2012 = 130 
 DEC-2012 = 40

Comment: My answer would be pretty similar to [Ashish](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16535470/1065197) but instead using a `HashMap` I would use a `LinkedHashMap` because you would want to have the elements to maintain the order in which the were entered, or maybe a `TreeMap<String, Double>` if you want them sorted. Still, a better idea would be using a `Set<BillsBean>` backed by a `LinkedHashSet<BillsBean>` and modify your `BillsBean` class to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods based on the `String monthYear` value.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for the suggestion Id certainly look into those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following method in your class and call it from main.

```
private static void calculateSum(List<BillsBean> billList) {
    Map<String,Double> sumMap=new HashMap<>();
    for(BillsBean bean:billList)
        if(sumMap.containsKey(bean.getMonthYear()))
            sumMap.put(bean.getMonthYear(), bean.getBill()+sumMap.get(bean.getMonthYear()));
        else
            sumMap.put(bean.getMonthYear(),bean.getBill());
    Iterator iter = sumMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = iter.next().toString();
        System.out.println("Year: "+key+" Bill: "+sumMap.get(key));
    }
 }
```

Comment: How would you modify this code if the BillsBean has more than 1 double field to add.  E.g. double tax, double fine.  Im not that good using Maps in Java

Comment: You will have to modify this line of code `    for(BillsBean bean:billList)
        if(sumMap.containsKey(bean.getMonthYear()))
            sumMap.put(bean.getMonthYear(), bean.getBill()+sumMap.get(bean.getMonthYear()));
        else
            sumMap.put(bean.getMonthYear(),bean.getBill());`

Answer (score 1):

You need simple iteration to get total. You can have two methods for this. Check the following code.

```
 public static  double getTotal(List<BillsBean> billsBeans,String monthYear) {
        double total=0.0d;;
        for(BillsBean bb : billsBeans) {
            if(bb.getMonthYear().equals(monthYear)) {
                total += bb.getBill();
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static HashMap<String,Double> getTotals(List<BillsBean> billsBeans) {
        HashMap<String,Double> totalMap = new HashMap();
        for(BillsBean bb : billsBeans) {
            Double billAmount = totalMap.get(bb.getMonthYear());
            if( billAmount == null) {
                billAmount = bb.getBill();
            } else {
                billAmount = billAmount.doubleValue() + bb.getBill();
            }
            totalMap.put(bb.getMonthYear(),billAmount);
        }
        return totalMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check out this, it may be help full to you, created custom class by extending the ArrayList and

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayList<BillsBean>{

    public double addAllBill(){
        double sum=0;
        Iterator<BillsBean> it = this.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            sum += it.next().getBill(); 
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public double addAllBill(String s1, String s2) throws ParseException{
        double sum=0;
        SimpleDateFormat monthYearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
        Date date1=null;
        Date date2=null;
        Date date3= null;
        if(s1 == null){
            date1 = monthYearFormat.parse("JAN-1900");
        }else{
            date1 = monthYearFormat.parse(s1);
        }
        if(s2 == null){
            date2 = monthYearFormat.parse("JAN-1900");
        }else{
            date2 = monthYearFormat.parse(s2);
        }
        Iterator<BillsBean> it = this.iterator();
        BillsBean bean=null;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            bean= it.next();
            date3= monthYearFormat.parse(bean.getMonthYear());
            if(date3.compareTo(date1)>=0 && date3.compareTo(date2)<=0)
                sum += bean.getBill();
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

in main check use the following line

System.out.println("Between Date:" + billList.addAllBill("DEC-2012","FEB-2013"));

Comment: very useful sir!!! ^_^